# Easy way to print Perl array? (with a little formatting)

Tags: perl

Is there an **easy** way to print out a Perl array with commas in between each element?

Writing a for loop to do it is pretty easy but not quite elegant....if that makes sense.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Just use [`join()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html):

```
# assuming @array is your array:
print join(", ", @array);
```

Comment: Or, if you want to be really dirty: `{local $,=', ';print @array}`.

Comment: There's more than one way to do it.. but this is the way that doesn't make the person maintaining the code after you hate you. Yes, perldoc perlvar exists, but I'd rather glance over "join ', ' @array" than hit up perlvar every other line to figure out what all the esoteric variables are doing.

Comment: @Oesor: That's why I called it dirty. But well, looking at the other answers, I'm not really the worst offender. :)

Comment: @musiKK I like it! It's something I'd use if I wanted to puzzle my fellow co workers. :)

Comment: This worked really nicely for printing the directory contents.
  
`print "current directory contains " . join(', ', <*>) . "\n";`

Answer (score 37):

You can use [`Data::Dump`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dump):

```
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
my @a = (1, [2, 3], {4 => 5});
dump(@a);
```

Produces:

```
"(1, [2, 3], { 4 => 5 })"
```

Comment: On Ubuntu/Mint, install the libdata-dump-perl package.

Comment: Best answer here! Works with multidimensional arrays too. Most flexible.

Answer (score 20):

If you're coding for the kind of clarity that would be understood by someone who is just starting out with Perl, the traditional this construct says what it means, with a high degree of clarity and legibility:

```
$string = join ', ', @array;
print "$string\n";
```

This construct is documented in `perldoc -f`[`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html).

However, I've always liked how simple `$,` makes it.  The special variable  `$"` is for interpolation, and the special variable `$,` is for lists.  Combine either one with dynamic scope-constraining '`local`' to avoid having ripple effects throughout the script:

```
use 5.012_002;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw/ 1 2 3 4 5 /;

{
    local $" = ', ';
    print "@array\n"; # Interpolation.
}
```

OR with $,:

```
use feature q(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw/ 1 2 3 4 5 /;
{
    local $, = ', ';
    say @array; # List
}
```

The special variables `$,` and `$"` are documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). The `local` keyword, and how it can be used to constrain the effects of altering a global punctuation variable's value is probably best described in [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local()).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 10):

Also, you may want to try [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html). Example:

```perl
use Data::Dumper;

# simple procedural interface
print Dumper($foo, $bar);
```

Comment: Data::Dumper is a standard module and is installed along with Perl.  To get a list of all the standard pragmatics and modules, see `pelrdoc perlmodlib`.

Answer (score 7):

For inspection/debugging check the [`Data::Printer`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aPrinter) module. It is meant to do one thing and one thing only:

> display Perl variables and objects on screen, properly formatted (to
>   be inspected by a human)

Example usage:

```
use Data::Printer;  
p @array;  # no need to pass references
```

The code above might output something like this (with colors!):

```
   [
       [0] "a",
       [1] "b",
       [2] undef,
       [3] "c",
   ]
```

Comment: Under Ubuntu one can install the `libdata-printer-perl` package.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply `print` it.

```
@a = qw(abc def hij);

print "@a";
```

You will got:

```
abc def hij
```

Comment: You have commas in the print because they are in each element of the array. You really should declare `use warnings;` and see what it says.

Answer (score 2):

```
# better than Dumper --you're ready for the WWW....

use JSON::XS;
print encode_json \@some_array
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Data::Dumper` :

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $GRANTstr = 'SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, TRIGGER';
$GRANTstr    =~ s/, /,/g;
my @GRANTs   = split /,/ , $GRANTstr;

print Dumper(@GRANTs) . "===\n\n";

print Dumper(\@GRANTs) . "===\n\n";

print Data::Dumper->Dump([\@GRANTs], [qw(GRANTs)]);
```

Generates three different output styles:

```
$VAR1 = 'SELECT';
$VAR2 = 'INSERT';
$VAR3 = 'UPDATE';
$VAR4 = 'DELETE';
$VAR5 = 'LOCK TABLES';
$VAR6 = 'EXECUTE';
$VAR7 = 'TRIGGER';
===

$VAR1 = [
          'SELECT',
          'INSERT',
          'UPDATE',
          'DELETE',
          'LOCK TABLES',
          'EXECUTE',
          'TRIGGER'
        ];
===

$GRANTs = [
            'SELECT',
            'INSERT',
            'UPDATE',
            'DELETE',
            'LOCK TABLES',
            'EXECUTE',
            'TRIGGER'
          ];
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you're looking for, but here's something I did for an assignment:

```
$" = ", ";
print "@ArrayName\n";
```

Comment: Where is this $" variable documented? Is there a name for it? Edit: found it here: https://perldoc.perl.org/variables

Answer (score 1):

Map can also be used, but sometimes hard to read when you have lots of things going on.

```
map{ print "element $_\n" }   @array;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried to run below, though. I think this's a tricky way.

```
map{print $_;} @array;
```