# Concat string with a separator

Tags: perl

```
$ ls /tmp/foo/
foo10.txt  foo11.txt  foo15.txt

$ cat ./foo.pl 
use warnings;
use strict;
use Cwd;
my $dir = cwd();
chdir '/tmp/foo';
my @files = glob "foo*.txt";
my $b = "";
for (0..$#files) {
  my ($a) = $files[$_] =~ m/foo(.*)\.txt/;
  $b = $b.",".$a;
}
chdir $dir;
print "$b\n";
```

Output:

```
$ perl ./foo.pl 
,10,11,15
```

How do I avoid first comma, just before 10? also please suggest if there is a better logic than this.

Comment: Use [`join`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) on a list, and don't use `$a` and `$b` as variable names---those are special and should only be used with `sort`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way to print Perl array? (with a little formatting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741101/easy-way-to-print-perl-array-with-a-little-formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
say join ', ', map { /foo(.*)\.txt/ } glob "foo*.txt";
```

Build the list/array first then use `join`.

Comment: Needn't be in one statement of course. Can build an array and do other needed things (and checks) in that loop, then print `join`ed array.